# On click event get selected value of google organization chart node in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, charts, google-visualization

I have created google organization chart in .Net MVC chart is displaying correctly. but i have to get some information on click event on chart node like their employee.id, employee.name.

I tried with below snippet code but however, it's not working.

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(chart1, 'ready', function () {
        alert("3");
        // grab a few details before redirecting
        google.visualization.events.addListener(chart.getChart(), 'select', function () {
            chartObject = chart.getChart();
            alert(data.getValue(chartObject.getSelection()[0].row, 0));
        }); 
    });
```

In Below code how and where to add click event code?

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
            //alert("dddd");
            // window.alert("hi!");
            //here http get method for get data from database
            $scope.chartData = [['Name', 'ReportsTo', 'tooltip']];
            $http.get('/home/getChartData').then(function (response) {
                var newobject = [['Name', 'ReportsTo', 'tooltip']];
                angular.forEach(response.data, function (val) {
                    newobject.push(
                        [
                         {
                            v: val.EmployeeID.toString(),
                            f: '<div class="customBox"><div>' + (val.FirstName + ' '
                                + val.LastName) +
                                '</div><div class="title" id="' + val.EmployeeID + '">'
                                + val.Title + '</div></div>'
                            },
                            (val.ReportsTo.toString() == "0" ? "" : val.ReportsTo.toString()),
                            (val.FirstName + ' ' + val.LastName)
                        ]
                        );
                })
                $scope.chartData = newobject;
            })
        }])
        app.directive('orgChart', function () {

            function link($scope, element, attrs) {
                var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(element[0]);
                $scope.$watch('chartData', function (value, oldvalue) {

                    if (!value) {
                        return;
                    }
                    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(value);
                    var options = {
                        'title': '',
                        'allowHtml': true
                    }
                    chart.draw(data, options);
                })
            }
            return {
                link: link
            };
        })
```

Chart:- On Click first node i have to genrate click event.
[image: chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code you tried to implement is for a `ChartWrapper`,
you are using an `OrgChart`

```
var chart = new google.visualization.OrgChart(element[0]);
```

try the following, which should immediately follow the above line ^

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
  var selection = chart.getSelection();
  if (selection.length > 0) {
    alert(data.getValue(selection[0].row, 0));
  }
});
```

note: be sure to check the length of the selection as above

the event will also fire when something is de-selected,
which will return an empty array,
causing this to fail --> `selection[0].row`

Comment: Click event generating but not getting any value could please guide me how to get i am using angular first time.